# To input symbols with utf8 codes beyond the standard utf8 packet in Latex

Tags: unicode, accents, input-encodings

I have input text for Latex with symbols like Ẃ  ẃ Ẅ ẅ Ỳ ỳ and so on and must translate it into pdf. The task came from the whole work of export from Library of Congress catalog to prepare article in LaTex. So lot of symbols in utf8 codes but not in the form of Latex comands just fall into Latex input. When translation begins there are error message in the form: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ĭ not set up for use with LaTeX. - with different utf8 symbols besides the standard list. All of them are like "Latin Accent" but of different form: Acute, Grave, Circumflex, Dieresis, Tilde, Caron, Macron, Breve, Overdot, Underdot.  So to overcome this I use in preambula commands like \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{$\hat{W}$}. It works but such symbols are a lot of. Do somebody knows packet to do such work totally on all such symbols? The example with text producing a lot of error messages is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{cmap}       % good PDF (pdflatex)

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}   

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B9}{\textquoteright}   % modifier letter prime
% like apostrof 

% Welsh and Cornish languages
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{$\hat{W}$}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0175}{$\hat{w}$}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0176}{$\hat{Y}$}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0177}{$\hat{y}$}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

Acides nucléiques et synthèse des protéines chez les végétaux: {[}actes du colloque international{]}, Strasbourg, 15-24 juillet 1976

Russko-moldavskiĭ zoologicheskiĭ slovarʹ. Gani︠a︡

Russkiĭ narodnyĭ lubok

Slovarʹ-spravochnik po shelkovodstvu. Gani︠a︡

Aėrokosmichesk kurʹer =: Aerospace courier

\end{document}
```

Environment:
Windows 7
Miktex 2.9
Texworks
pdflatex

Question: Do somebody knows packet to do such work totally on all such symbols?

Comment: You shouldn't use math `$\hat{Y}$`. Use  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{\^W}`

Comment: Ulrike - thank you for your comment. Can you say why it is bad, what complicated situations i can have?

Comment: Math and text fonts can differ.  Using a math font to fake a missing text glyph is hackish.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` and choose a font that has the symbols you need. Below I've used the `Doulos SIL` font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}  
\begin{document}
Acides nucléiques et synthèse des protéines chez les végétaux: {[}actes du colloque international{]}, Strasbourg, 15-24 juillet 1976

Russko-moldavskiĭ zoologicheskiĭ slovarʹ. Gani︠a︡

Russkiĭ narodnyĭ lubok

Slovarʹ-spravochnik po shelkovodstvu. Gani︠a︡

Aėrokosmichesk kurʹer =: Aerospace courier
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Greate thanks, Sverre today I first time used XeLatex as you had recommended - it works. Russian + different types Latin Accent - it works with Doulos SIL. After that I tryed to copy text from example from pdf to word 2013 and the result text was the same as in pdf. This last I could not understand because i had not installed Doulos SIL in system (Windows 7) but simply copyed it into folder where i produced latex-pdf file.

Comment: @vmk It just means that the font used as a default by Word 2013 has the characters you need as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're tied to pdflatex, you can use `newunicodechar` for easing the definition of unsupported characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B9}{$'$}   % modifier letter prime
% like apostrof

% Welsh and Cornish languages
\newunicodechar{Ŵ}{\^W}
\newunicodechar{ŵ}{\^w}
\newunicodechar{Ŷ}{\^Y}
\newunicodechar{ŷ}{\^y}
\newunicodechar{ĭ}{\u{\i}}
\newunicodechar{ė}{\.e}

\begin{document}

Acides nucléiques et synthèse des protéines chez les végétaux: 
[actes du colloque international], Strasbourg, 15-24 juillet 1976

Russko-moldavskiĭ zoologicheskiĭ slovarʹ. Gan\t{ia}

Russkiĭ narodnyĭ lubok

Slovarʹ-spravochnik po shelkovodstvu. Gan\t{ia}

Aėrokosmichesk kurʹer =: Aerospace courier

ŴŵŶŷ

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's no way to input the half ties with UTF-8, I'm afraid.

Shouldn't `zoologicheskiĭ` be `zoologičeskiĭ` instead? Similarly, `shelkovodstvu` should perhaps be `šelkovodstvu`.

Comment: egreg, help you for help